# TestFlight setup mvvmcross

Tags: android, mvvmcross, testflight

I am trying to setup MvxTrace to log to testflight. I use the bindings project from Bradley Hall http://www.behindthecode.net/wordpress/testflight-for-xamarin-android/ The Method of the testflight liftoff has to have the Android application to hookup.
How do i get that inside my trace file. I have tried the IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity but is not registered when i start init the tracefile.

Regards Thomas

Comment: Why do you need the top activity? What is 'start init my trace file?'. I believe you should be able to follow the tutorial exactly as it is in that blog.

Comment: Sorry Stuart the init was in the traceclass where i wolud start the testflight. it works if i create a class that inherits from Android Application. I Thought that MvvmCross framework created the android application, and i would have to get it through MvvmCross. It all works now, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bradley provided some additional information.

http://www.behindthecode.net/wordpress/testflight-for-xamarin-android/#comment-57