# How do I setup TestFlight with an MvvmCross Android application

Tags: android, mvvmcross, testflight

I am trying to set up TestFlight in a MvvmCross Android application.  I've created a bindings project following Bradley Hall's post http://www.behindthecode.net/wordpress/testflight-for-xamarin-android/

I'm not sure how to change the application constructor in the core PCL library to include parameters for the following:

```
[Application]
    public class MyApp : Application
    {
        public MyApp(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer) { }
```

Since it is a PCL I won't be able to include the bindings project.  I thought I might be able to do this through the MvxAndroidSetup class, but the constructor parameters are required so Jni can consume the class.

So how can I set up the Mvx Android app to include TestFlight?

this is similar to [TestFlight setup mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269734/testflight-setup-mvvmcross) but I think it is different enough to be a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same  as the other question - [TestFlight setup mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269734/testflight-setup-mvvmcross)

The app in the pcl project is an MvxApplication object - used to provide the view model locator and the app start navigation - but this is a completely separate object to the Android application, to the WindowsPhone Application, to the iOS AppDelegate, etc. These platform specific application objects can live in the native projects.